# CSS transform using a prop, within a map in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to rotate an image based on a value gained from the an array I'm working through using `map`. This is what the code looks like:

```
render() {
    return (
        this.props.currentForecast.list.map(item => (

                <div className="weatherTile" key={item.dt_txt}>
                    <p>{item.dt}</p>
                    <img src={"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + item.weather[0].icon + ".png"} />
                    <p>{item.main.temp}</p>
                    <p>{item.weather[0].description}</p>
                    <img src="img/arrow.svg" style={{transform: rotate(${item.wind.deg})}} />
                    <p>{item.wind.speed}mph</p>
                </div>
            ))
        )
    }
```

However, the style attr on the img gives this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Invariant Violation): The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Searching Stack Overflow and the documentation, I can't find a way to get around this while still using the value I need to use. The alternatives I've tried are as follow:

```
 <img src="img/arrow.svg" style={`transform: rotate(${item.wind.deg})`} />
 <img src="img/arrow.svg" style={{`transform: rotate(${item.wind.deg})`}} />
 <img src="img/arrow.svg" style={{transform: rotate(${item.wind.deg})}} />
```

All of which break the page in some way. What's the right way of doing this?

Comment: Can u share the array? What is deg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in the style map should be a string. So surround it with quotes. Also since presumably `item.wind.deg` returns a number, you will need to add 'deg' after it for a valid syntax for the `rotate` function.

```
<img src="img/arrow.svg" style={{transform: `rotate(${item.wind.deg}deg)`}} />
```

Comment: That doesn't throw an error - but the img doesn't render with a style tag or rotate, so the plot has thickened.

Comment: If you look in the devtools for whatever browser, does it show the transform property being applied to the img component at all? Maybe the syntax isn't 100% correct in which case it would be crossed out.

Comment: In vanilla dev tools there's nothing at all - no style tag and nothing where styles from a stylesheet would be. But in the React dev tools this shows up in props: 

style: {transform: "rotate(346.5)"}

Comment: It's not appearing on the dom tree since the syntax is wrong. Appearently rotate expects the value between the bracket to be in the form of '90deg', as in having the letters 'deg' after the degrees. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ah! I should have spotted that myself. Thanks a lot, that's sorted it.